# Java library function to find shadow file in different directory

Tags: java, file

I often have code where I loop over a directory (including subdirectories) and need to move / copy the file to a different directory. What I find tedious is the process of identifying where the file will go. I have often done that, usually like this:

```
File shadow = new File(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()
                        .replace(
                             sourceFolder.getAbsolutePath(),
                             targetFolder.getAbsolutePath()
                        )
              );
```

My question: is there a standard routine to do this or something similar in any major open source library? I didn't find one in [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) anyway...

I am not looking for complete move / copy solutions, I know tons of those. I just want the equivalent of the above code.

---

An Example, as requested:

Source folder:

```
src/main/resources
```

Target folder:

```
target/classes
```

Source file:

```
src/main/resources/com/mycompany/SomeFile.txt
```

Target file (the one I'm looking for):

```
target/classes/com/mycompany/SomeFile.txt
```

(I usually do stuff like this in a maven context, hence these folders but they could be non-maven folders, as well, the question has nothing to do with maven)

Comment: What is `sourceFolder`? Is that just the parent of `sourceFile`? Can you please provide examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for I have never found either but it will exist soon when JDK 7 (eventually) crawls out the door.

[Path.relativize(Path)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) (Java 7 API)

For now I would stick to your current solution (or roll your own equivalent of the above).

Comment: This is great, I'll definitely use this a lot, thanks (+1). Yes of course, I know my code works, but it's boilerplate that I have written for x projects and I hate not having a shortcut for code like that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils` [concat](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method?  It takes a base directory (your target) and file-name to append.  You would need to calculate the sourceFolder prefix ("src/main/resources".length()) and do a substring.  Something like:

```
File shadow = new File(FilenameUtils.concat(targetFolder.getAbsolutePath(),
    sourceFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(prefixLength));
```

Not much better than rolling you own though.

---

Apache's `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` also has functionality that you might use although I don't see a specific solution to your question:

- [FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29)
- [FileUtils.copyDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)
- [FileUtils.moveDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

You could use `copyDirectory`  with a `FileFilter` to choose which files to move over:

- [FileUtils.copyDirectory(File, File, FileFilter)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.FileFilter%29)

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I know all these methods. I just want the method that does what the code I wrote does.

Comment: Figured that you did.  How about using copyDirectory with a FileFilter?  That should track the src and destination paths for you.

Comment: As I said, I am not looking for a copy solution, but for a generic mechanism to identify a file's sibling in another directory (this has many applications, only one of them being to copy the file).